# How do I get a string from a curl response for a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, curl, grep

The bash script sends a curl. The curl response example is following:

```
{"code":"2aaea70fdccd7ad11e4ee8e82ec26162","nonce":1541355854942}
```

I need to get the code "2aaea70fdccd7ad11e4ee8e82ec26162" (without quotes) and use it in the bash script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `jq` to extract the value from the JSON, and command substitution to capture the output of the command:

```
code=$(curl ... | jq -r '.code')
```

The `-r` (`--raw`) prints the string directly instead of quoting it as in a JSON.

Comment: this request in jenkins "BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --silent ${BUILD_URL}api/json | jq -r '.result')" gives me "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 18"

Comment: What's on the line 1 column 18?

Comment: you mean in the json response of curl ?

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya: Yes. It's clearly complaining it's not a valid JSON.

Comment: {"_class":"hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild","actions":[{"_class":"hudson.model.CauseAction","causes":[{"_class":"hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause","shortDescription":"Démarré par l'utilisateur Youssef Boudaya","userId":"youssefboudaya","userName":"Youssef Boudaya"}]}, ...

Comment: Are you sure what the Jenkins gets? I don't see any problem in column 18 here.

Comment: the response is way long but this is the beginning of the curl response

Comment: Are you testing it on the actual Jenkins instance or from somewhere else? Are you sure the BUILD_URL value is populated correctly?

Comment: i am running in the build of my freestyle project in "run a shell script" and it's getting the url of the current build so i think it's correct

Comment: When I run the json through `jq`, I'm getting no errors :-o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231934/discussion-between-youssef-boudaya-and-choroba).

Answer (score 4):

You can also achieve it by `sed` command if you don't want to install jq:

```
json=`curl ...`
code=$(echo "$json" | sed -nE 's/.*"code":"([^\"]*)",".*/\1/p')
```

Comment: The order of keys is usually not guaranteed in JSON.

Comment: `{"unused":{"code":"wrong_code"},"code":"correct_code"}` - don't parse json with regex, use a proper json parser. also `{"code":"code_with_\"_lol"}`

Comment: @hanshenrik I got what you mean , but the solution is designed specifically for the problem  stated in this question and not for a general purpose one .anyway thanks for the comment